# Can I use TIMEDIFF to calculate time difference for 12 hours format

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL. I'm trying to calculate the difference of hours between two TIME variables.

I tried using the TIMEDIFF() function:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(sleep_till, sleep_from);
```

But this only works when sleep_from is before 00:00:00 i.e. 23:00:00 or earlier.

For example, SELECT TIMEDIFF('18:00:00', '07:00:00') would return -11:00:00 though I'd like it to return 13:00:00. Or SELECT TIMEDIFF('02:00:00', '03:00:00') would return -01:00:00

Also, say I want to do SELECT TIMEDIFF('02:00:00', '03:00:00') and have it return 23:00:00 instead of -01:00:00, is it possible to use TIMEDIFF but without specifying the date e.g. TIMEDIFF('2021-12-16 02:00:00', '2021-12-15 03:00:00')?

Is this the limitation of the TIMEDIFF function? And how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add 24 hours when `sleep_from > sleep_till`.

```sql
SELECT TIMEDIFF(sleep_till + INTERVAL CASE WHEN sleep_from > sleep_till
                                           THEN 24
                                           ELSE 0
                                           END HOUR, sleep_from)
...
```